# "Too many SOQL queries: 101" alerts

Tags: trigger, error-messages

Since I deployed the Apex trigger below, I got many "Too many SOQL queries: 101" alerts which were caused by other triggers.

Here is the code of the new trigger:

```
trigger calcBusinessHoursSecurity on Case (before insert, before update) { 
    BusinessHours stdBusinessHours = [select id from businesshours where Name = 'Security (Weekday)']; 
    BusinessHours stdBusinessHours2 = [select id from businesshours where Name = 'Security(officer)'];

    for (Case c : Trigger.new) { 
        if ((c.CreatedDate != NULL) && (stdBusinessHours != NULL) && (c.Priority == 'Low')  && (c.RecordTypeId == '01220000000FuOP')) { 
            c.SLA_for_FR_Sec__c = BusinessHours.addGmt (stdBusinessHours.id, c.CreatedDate , 18 * 60 * 60 * 1000L); 
        } else {
            if ((c.CreatedDate != NULL) && (stdBusinessHours != NULL) &&(c.Priority == 'Medium')&& (c.RecordTypeId == '01220000000FuOP')) {
                c.SLA_for_FR_Sec__c = BusinessHours.addGmt (stdBusinessHours.id, c.CreatedDate , 9 * 60 * 60 * 1000L); 
               } else { 
                    if ((c.CreatedDate != NULL) && (stdBusinessHours2 != NULL) && (c.Priority == 'High')&& (c.RecordTypeId == '01220000000FuOP')) {
                        c.SLA_for_FR_Sec__c= BusinessHours.addGmt (stdBusinessHours2.id, c.CreatedDate , 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000L); 
                    } else {
                        if ((c.CreatedDate != NULL) && (stdBusinessHours2 != NULL) && (c.Priority == 'Urgent')&& (c.RecordTypeId == '01220000000FuOP')) {
                            c.SLA_for_FR_Sec__c= BusinessHours.addGmt (stdBusinessHours2.id, c.CreatedDate , 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000L); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible that these alerts are related to the trigger that I wrote?

Thanks in advance!
Lihod

Comment: It seems unlikely that the problem comes from this trigger. In your others triggers, do you have SOQL query in for loop ? Or something like that ?

Comment: It is not that specific trigger that is causing the issue, but rather that all the triggers run when the cases are updated cause more than 100 queries to run, and that violates the governor limits. 
I'm guessing the triggers were in a delicate balance before yesterday where they were running just under 100 queries, and this trigger I  just added pushed it over the edge. I believe I need to evaluate all of the existing triggers and look for places where queries can be consolidated.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but maybe you should combine those 2 queries at the start into a single trigger.  This will save you a single query, but the code you posted is not the root of your problem.  I would also change all of your nested **if** statements into **else if** statements for better readability as well.

Comment: Go through your other triggers and see if you can move any of your repetitive logic into classes

Comment: Thank you all, @dphil - since I new on the development field, would you be kind enough to let me show me how to combine the queries at the start and how to use the else if.

Comment: @LihodRachmilevitch You can write a single query to get both responses, and then toss them into a map according to name or you can instead just loop through comparing the name and assigning to a specific obj.  About the if/else statements though... you might want to google some of the basics of programming.  This isn't really a site good for learning the basics of programming but is great for Salesforce (or other stackexchange website) specific problems.